# Parsing nested object structure in bottom up approach

Tags: c#, .net, linq, tree

```
public class Group
{
    public int ID;
    public bool Earned;
    public bool Available;

    public List<Group> ChildGroups;
    public List<Item> ChildItems;
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID;
    public bool Earned;
    public bool Available;
}

public class Evaluator
{
    public List<Group> FindEarned(Group source)
    {
        //Filter implementation

        foreach (Group grp in source.Groups)
        {
            grp.Items = grp.Items.Where(
                                        x => x.Earned == true).ToList();

            if (grp.Groups != null && grp.Groups.Count > 0)
            {
                grp.Groups = FilterEarned(grp);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        return source.Groups;
    }

}
```

My find earned method should return list of groups where any of child group or item are in earned state. 
Example:

```
Group1 - Pending
  -Group11 -pending
  -Group12 -pending
  -Group13 -Pending
  -Item11 -Pending
  -Item12 -Pending
 Group2
  -Group21 -pending
  --Group211 -pending
  ---Item2111 - earned 
  -Group22 -pending
  -Group23 -Pending
  -Item21 -Pending
  -Item22 -Pending
```

Method should return

```
 Group2
  -Group21 -pending
  --Group211 -pending
  ---Item2111 - earned
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got you right, but if you need to filter out all not Earned items and groups, you can use this extension method. It's not very linqy, because it have to count children where Earned = true, and it's also creates new groups, otherwise you initial data will be corrupted.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Group> EarnedGroups(this IEnumerable<Group> data)
    {
        foreach (var group in data)
        {
            var items = group.ChildItems.Where(x => x.Earned).ToList();
            var groups = group.ChildGroups.EarnedGroups().ToList();
            if (items.Count > 0 || groups.Count > 0 || group.Earned)
                yield return new
                        Group
                        {
                            ID = group.ID,
                            Available = group.Available,
                            Earned = group.Earned,
                            ChildItems = items,
                            ChildGroups = groups
                       };
        }
    }
```